# Extraer año y mes de una fecha dada

Tags: sql-server

Tenemos en SQL 2012 la tabla de transacciones de inventario PartTran en la cual el campo TranDate trae la fecha de la transacción. Mediante un `select` necesito extraer el año y el mes en formato carácter, es decir, para una transacción hecha en cualquier día de enero de 2018, la variables mes quede "01" y año "2018", para febrero la variable mes quede "02" y año "2018" y así sucesivamente. Este el el `select`:

```
SELECT P.PartNum AS Producto,
       P.TranType AS Tipo,
       P.TranQty AS Cantidad, 
       month(P.TranDate) AS Mes,
       year(P.TranDate) AS Ano 
FROM PartTran P
```

Tal como lo tengo planteado, el `select` trae los resultados en enteros: 1 para enero, 2 para febrero, ETC.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT P.PartNum AS Producto,
      P.TranType AS Tipo,
      P.TranQty AS Cantidad, 
      (FORMAT(P.TranDate, 'MM') AS Date) as Mes,
      (FORMAT(P.TranDate, 'YYYY') AS Date) as 'Año'
FROM PartTran P
```

No recuerdo la sintaxis correcta, pero algo así debe de funcionarte, el format te permite obtener un valor específico para una fecha dada.

Comment: Probare con FORMAT.

Answer (score 0):

Esta puede ser una opción

```
SELECT P.PartNum AS Producto,
   P.TranType AS Tipo,
   P.TranQty AS Cantidad, 
   RIGHT(CAST(POWER(10,2)+MONTH(P.TranDate) AS varchar(3)),2) AS Mes
   cast(year(P.TranDate) as varchar(4)) AS Ano 
FROM PartTran P
```